# Индексация строк в MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Можно ли как-то проиндексировать строки в запросе, чтобы выбрать нужную? Я попытался сделать это через функцию ROW_NUMBER(), но дело в том, что это оконная функция.

```
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Client_ID), Client_ID FROM Apartments_and_clients 
WHERE Apartment_ID = 1
```

Я попробовал сделать по-другому:

```
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Client_ID), Client_ID FROM Apartments_and_clients 
WHERE Apartment_ID = 1 AND (SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Client_ID), Client_ID FROM Apartments_and_clients 
WHERE Apartment_ID = 1) = 2
```

но дело в том, что запрос возвращает больше 1 результата.

Comment: Задача совершенно непонятна. Опишите лучше примером... PS. Первый запрос синтаксически верен.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю вам поможет [CTE](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
   SELECT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Client_ID ) AS rn,
         Client_ID
   FROM  Apartments_and_clients
   WHERE Apartment_ID = 1
   )
SELECT
      CTE.rn,
      CTE.Client_ID
FROM  CTE
WHERE CTE.rn = 1;
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло)
с переменными так же будет работать? Я собираюсь вставить всё в триггер.

Comment: @vanyavanya *спасибо, помогло* Что, реально то, что надо? тогда нафига CTE? достаточно ТОР1 при правильной сортировке.

Comment: TOP 1 при DESC?)

Comment: SELECT TOP (1) @Val  = Id FROM Table Where Smth = 1 Order by Smth

Comment: @vanyavanya если вам помог мой ответ, проголосуйте за него и отметьте как верный